# Php laravel project works differently when deployed on cloud

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, amazon-web-services, shared-hosting

I have a php laravel project that works well on my localhost with xampp. But when i upload it to any hosting, aws or shared hosting. A certain dashboard controller does not work as expected. I have tried all possible ways but no luck. I even build an ec2 instance with xampp, same version as the one on my local ubuntu machine. But i still get the same issue, the moment the project is hosted the one index controller function on my dashboard messes up. It filters data from the db that has relationships.

I tried multiple solutions hoping that it works just like how it works on my localhost. I even tried building a lamp server with the same exact mysql and php version as my local project, but still no luck.

Here is the troublesome controller function

```
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $user = auth()->user();
    
        if ($user->is_job) {
            $programs = Job::where('published', 1)->get();
            $programs = DashboardHelper::multipleJobResults($programs, $user->id);
        } else {
            if ($user->is_admin) {
                // Show all scholarships if the user is an admin
                $scholarships = Scholarship::query()
                    ->where('deadline', '>', Carbon::now())
                    ->where('published', 1)
                    ->get();
            } else {
                $metadata = UserMetaData::where('user_id', $user->id)->first();
                $userCategoryName = $metadata ? $metadata->category : config('app.user_default_category', 'ScienceEngineering');
    
                $scholarshipCategories = ScholarshipCategory::query()
                    ->where('name', $userCategoryName)
                    ->get();
    
                $scholarshipCategoryId = $scholarshipCategories->first()->id;
    
                $scholarships = Scholarship::query()
                    ->where('deadline', '>', Carbon::now())
                    ->where('published', 1)
                    ->whereHas('category', function ($query) use ($scholarshipCategoryId) {
                        $query->where('id', $scholarshipCategoryId);
                    })
                    ->get();
            }
            $scholarships = $scholarships->sortBy('name');
    
            $programs = DashboardHelper::multipleResults($scholarships, $user->id);
        }
    
        return view('user.dashboard.dashboard', compact('programs'));
    }
```

It should be able to show the user programs in their category as per their usermetadata. It does that well on localhost, but then on cloud, it shows nothing. No programs, just an empty list.Even though i manually attach a category to a scholarship(which is a relationship, category id is foreign key in scholarships table).

But on localhost, it's all good.

Comment: Why is this tagged with JS? You haven't shared any such code. Also, what have you tried to resolve the problem?

Comment: Ere you sure that the relevant data is as you expect? could it be that the data in the cloud is missing something - try executing the SQL directy and comapring that to your expected output

Comment: @JoSSte , i have executed sql query directly in phpmyadmin, and it gives me an empty scholarships table. On both localhost and cloud

'''
SELECT * FROM scholarships
WHERE deadline > NOW()
AND published = 1
AND EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM scholarship_categories
    WHERE scholarships.id = scholarship_categories.id
    AND scholarship_categories.id = 3
);

'''

Comment: @NicoHaase i thought there could be a problem with my frontend js

Comment: @AnthonyBadebye If the data is as you expect, and queries work with similar results both places, then my best bid is to simplify your query a bit at a time, and try that out until you find the error... remember to only modify one bit at a time to avoid ending in a situation where you have changed five things and don't know which solved the issue...

Comment: Please add all clarifcation to your question by editing it. What makes you think that this could be a JS problem? You could simply inspect the markup and check whether it contains the data it should contain. If it does, PHP is not to blame - if it does not, you should check your PHP code first and not the JS processing of it's output

Comment: @JoSSte The localhost too can suddenly refuse to show the programs for a user. Like right now, on localhost, am in a user account and can't see their programs, but when i go to scholarships table and attach a scholarship category id, it shows the user that very scholarship program without the rest that were previously attached. I'm quite confused now. I'm really sorry if i might sound unclear but I've been fighting this issue for weeks and i'm losing my mind.

Comment: @AnthonyBadebye what sort of tests do you have in place to verify the behavious of your application? have you considered creating some test runs to ensure the behaviour of your application (either with something like [postman](https://www.postman.com/) or selenium)

Comment: @JoSSte do you mean testing my routes individually ?

Comment: @AnthonyBadebye You wrote "suddenly" - that implies time has gone by, and maybe that something has changed causing unforeseen results. If you make a testcase fetching your error-prone page 1000 times, and make sure that nothing is changing besides this (triggers. cronjobs, scheduled tasks, etc) and the results are varying, your issue is definitely code. My next step would be to go a step further down and do some repeated tests, or if you have some timestamps  in your query make sure that any rounding is done correctly - you need to find a pattern.